# Laravel 5, Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

My Controller :

```
 public function show($id){
    $user_id_1_connections = Connection::whereUser_id_1AndConnection_status($id, 1)->get();
    $user_id_2_connections = Connection::whereUser_id_2AndConnection_status($id, 1)->get();
    return view('connection.showConnection',['user_id_1_connections' => $user_id_1_connections, 'user_id_2_connections' => $user_id_2_connections]);
}
```

My Model :

```
protected $table = 'connections';
protected $fillable = ['user_id_1','user_id_2','connection_status'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

My Blade :

```
@foreach($user_id_1_connections as $user_id_1_connection)
{{ $user_id_1_connection->user->name }}
{{ $comment->user->name }}
@endforeach
@foreach($user_id_2_connections as $user_id_2_connection)
{{ $user_id_2_connection->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

I have made foreign key to user_id_1 and user_id_2 to users table.

```
$table->integer('user_id_1')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id_1')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id_2')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id_2')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

But when I'm running this code. It's showing the error :
Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: This can happen anywhere - you should have a filename and line number in the error message, please post that information first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is probably that you don't have `user` assigned to each connection so instead of:

```
{{ $user_id_1_connection->user->name }}
```

you should write rather something like this:

```
{{ $user_id_1_connection->user ? $user_id_1_connection->user->name : 'unknown' }}
```

same in all other places when you use `$x->y->z` syntax. To display `z` you should make sure `$x->y` is not null

Comment: Yes, It's correct but I have made two foreign key to same user table as posted above. So, I want to display the name of user whose foreign reference is user_id_1 and user_id_2. How to do this??

Comment: You have to create 2 user relationships and in each define as 2nd parameter valid column (user_id_1 or user_id_2)

Comment: public function user_id_1()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id_1');
    }

    public function user_id_2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id_2');
    }

Comment: Yes, I currently made this relation in my model and I'm calling the ''@foreach($user_id_2_connections as $user_id_2_connection)
    {{ $user_id_2_connection->user_id_2 ? $user_id_2_connection->user_id_2->name : 'unknown' }}
@endforeach" in my blade, but it's showing same error.

Comment: Please create new question and include in this your whole model and description

Comment: Done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773439/laravel-using-two-user-relationships-in-model